# Getting errors NIntegrate::nlim and NIntegrate::slwcon

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, wavelet-analysis

Here is the modified question:

First: Define

`phi[x_]:=Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x < 1}}, 0]`

`psi1[x_] := (phi[2 x] - phi[2 x - 1])`;

`psijk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi1[2^j x - k],0 <= j}, {(2)^j psi1[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}];`

I am trying to solve the equation in the below picture by finding an approximation solution for u(x) using wavelets. What I did is as follows: I used wavelet functions and substitute the wavelet instead of u(x).

I multiplied both sides of the equation by `psijk[x,l,s]` and integrate both sides from 0 to 1, this known in wavelets as the Galerkin Method. So we have the following system,

`Sum[C [j, k]* PSI[j, k, l, s], {j, -2, 2}, {k, -4, 3}, {l, -2, 2}, {s, -4, 3}] = NIntegrate[f[x]*psijk[x, l, s], {x, 0, 1}]`

where

`PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] := NIntegrate[psijk[x, j, k]* psijk[x, l, s], {x, 0, 1}]- 
NIntegrate[psijk[x, l, s] * NIntegrate[psijk[t, j, k]*(1/(-t + x)^(1/4)), {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]-NIntegrate[psijk[x, l, s]*NIntegrate[psijk[t, j, k]*(1/(-t + x)^(1/4)), {t, 0, 1}], {x,0, 1}]`;

and

`f[x_]:=16/165 (-1 + x)^(3/4) + 48/385 (-1 + x)^(3/4) x + x^2 + (256 (-1 +x)^(3/4) x^2)/1155 - (256 x^(11/4))/231 - x^3 - (512 (-1 + x)^(3/4) x^3)/1155 + (1024 x^(15/4))/1155,` and `C[j,k]` to be found!

Then to find these coefficients,  I defined,

`ce = ArrayReshape[Table[PSI[j, k, l, s], {j, -2, 2}, {k, -4, 3}, {l, -2, 2}, {s, -4, 3}], {40, 40}];`

`coef=NIntegrate[f[x]*psijk[x, l, s], {x, 0, 1}]`

and

`ae = PseudoInverse[ce].coef;`

However, I am getting error and the solution is incorrect as the exact solution is u[x]=x^2(1-x).

The errors came as some comments is from the ranges {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, but I dont know how to fix this issue as the method I used is by integrating both sides of the equation from 0 to 1.

I hope the question is clear for everyone. [image]
Your help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Try different `Method`s you can find within `NIntegrate`.

Comment: You should interchange the integration parameters `NIntegrate[..., {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]`-> `NIntegrate[..., {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}]]` (first error!)

Comment: What is your reason for including the definition of `f` in this question? It doesn't seem to called any other function in the question.

Comment: When `t == 1` and `x == 0`, `(-t + x)^(1/4)` is complex.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine the iterated integrals into multiple integrals, apply `PiecewiseExpand` to the last integral, and further specify the singularity `t == x` in the last integral, it seems to work.

```
PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] := 
  NIntegrate[psijk[x, j, k]*psijk[x, l, s], {x, 0, 1}] - 
   NIntegrate[
    psijk[x, l, s]*psijk[t, j, k]*(1/(-t + x)^(1/4)),
    {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}] - 
   NIntegrate[
    psijk[x, l, s]*psijk[t, j, k]*(1/(-t + x)^(1/4)) // PiecewiseExpand,
    {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> t == x];

PSI[1, 1, 1, 1]
(*  0.767956 + 0.0606109 I  *)
```

You get a complex value because near `t == 1`, `x == 0`, the factor `(-t + x)^(1/4)` is complex.

Comment: Might want to set a finite `AccuracyGoal`, since the integrals may be zero.  E.g. `AccuracyGoal ->12`.

Comment: How we can avoid x-t to be a negative? I need it only positive for any value in the domain of 0<t<x<1.

Comment: @Mutaz The integration ranges you give in the 3rd integral are `{x, 0, 1}` and `{t, 0, 1}`.  Perhaps you meant to put `{t, 0, x}` for the `t` range in the 3rd, just as you did in the 2nd integral?  (If you do that, the integral is computed without any fuss. No need for `PiecewiseExpand` either.)

Comment: But it supposed to be as it is

Comment: @Mutaz If `(-t+x)^(1/4)` and `{x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}` are both correct, then complex numbers cannot be avoided.  It is not a numerical issue, but a mathematical one.